# How do I change the default boot option on rEFIt?

Tags: macos, startup, efi

I have two copies of OS X (10.6 and 10.7). By default rEFIt boots 10.6. However, I want to make it boot 10.7 instead.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to edit the rEFIt configuration file. Since version 0.14, the configuration file has supported adding a default boot selection, as documented in the [news section of the website](http://refit.sourceforge.net/#news).

However, there isn't very clear documentation on how exactly to do this on rEFIt's website. You could just open the conf file, or view the default on their SVN repo [here](https://refit.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/refit/trunk/dist/efi/refit/refit.conf). This [blog](http://hungrycoder.xenexbd.com/tutorial/setting-linux-as-default-in-refit-boot-loader.html) does have an example and some documentation that I've used before in a similar situation. You'll want to use the digit option instead of the OS type option (1-N, vs L,W,M).